# C# - How would I return an enum instead of the enums stored value?

Tags: c#, random, enums, typeof

I have a problem with my code but I'm not sure where.
I'm attempting to return an enum value from an enum collection/class.
However when I try do this, instead of returning the value, it returns a number of the actual enum value.

E.G

```
thisisamaptype = 5;
```

would return "5" instead of the Enum name its self.

Is there a way to get the Enum value from the associated number provided by the method?

```
    Random rnd = new Random();
    public static MapTypes GetMapType(string Type)
    {
        switch (Type.ToLower())
        {
            default:
            case "default":
                return (MapTypes)(rnd.Next(1,Enum.GetNames(typeof(MapTypes)).Length)); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have a bug in that `rnd.Next(1, n)` won't **ever** cause the first value of your enum to be returned. Have you assigned values to your enum, or is this desired behaviour?

Comment: On another note, you really should make your Random variable static.

Comment: Don't worry I have, I just done it for the sake of an example.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me, so I'm confused.

```
// Used my own enums
public enum MapTypes
{
    One, Two, Three, Four, Five
}

// I had to make this static since it's being used in a static method
static Random rnd = new Random();
public static MapTypes GetMapType(string Type)
{
    switch (Type.ToLower())
    {
        default:
        case "default":
            // Changed first parameter of Next to 0 to include the first enum in the randomization
            return (MapTypes)(rnd.Next(0, Enum.GetNames(typeof(MapTypes)).Length));
            break;
    }
}
```

Usage of your code in a console application:

```
MapTypes myMapType = GetMapType("default");
Console.WriteLine(myMapType);

Console.WriteLine("Done");
Console.ReadLine();
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Oh I see! I think I've worked out the problem. It was to do with some processes before that method. Thank you!

Comment: Please don't vote down and leave the post. Stack Overflow is essential for me if I need help and people keep voting down random posts which leads to me getting banned,

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand you correctly, your method is returning the enum type, so with the value returned from the method, you can use .ToString() to output "thisisamaptype"